# List <Objects> to String[]

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to query from a database and it returns List and I needed a string[] of the medName field

```
public List<Medicines> selectMeds()
        {
            try
            {

                using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "mediapp.db")))
                {
                    return connection.Table<Medicines>().ToList();

                }
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.Info("SQLiteEx", ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

while the Medicines class is

```
[Table("Medicines")]
    public class Medicines
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string medName { get; set; }
        public string medDesc { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I query one column from the sqlite database to string[]? or can I convert the Medicine object to string[], getting only the values for medName?

Comment: try : `connection.Table<Medicines>().Select( c=> c.medName).ToArray();`

Comment: add this as answer @EhsanSajjad so I could mark yours. It works! Thanks

Comment: @jtyg added that.

Comment: I would not change this method at all. I would apply the solution exposed here and in the duplicate in the code point where you need the string list using the `List<Medicines>` returned by this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to project the your `Table<Medicines>` using `Select` and then materialize the query to array by calling `ToArray` method:

```
var meds = connection.Table<Medicines>().Select(med => med.medName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply select over the table content like :

```
string[] meds = connection.Table<Medicines>().ToList().Select(x=>x.medName).ToArray();
```